# Wordpress comment linking not working (#comments)

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe

I have narrowed down the problem to a plugin 'Mailchimp Social Wordpress'. The problem is when trying to link to the comment section of the post using http://trentaughey.com/test/#comments the page starts of in right position at the comment section of the post but when the page has finished loading it jumps to the top of the post page. I think the problem may have something to do with the fact the plugin uses iframes, does anyone know a possible way of fixing this issue other than removing the plugin?

Comment: Your link seems to be working atm, no jumping to the top of the post.

Comment: Yeah managed to fix it by suppressing piece of javascript in the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commenting out the html code in the widget.php as shown below fixed the issue.

```
<script src="http://trentaughey.com/wp-content/plugins/mailchimp_social_wp/templates/css/iframes/jquery.responsiveiframe.js"></script>
```